# How to link topology edges at nodes?

Tags: qgis

How can make topology at nodes, link?

if nodes layer a and links layer b, 
they have correlation each other.

then how can make topology for them?

for example, edit some nodes' location then change links location automatically.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please either ask a friend or colleague, who speaks English more fluently, or use any online available text translation tool in order to make your question more intelligible. Currently I got no real idea, what you're asking.